# Associate app user with facebook user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm wondering if there is any way to associate a user of my app's username to the facebook user?

I have a web app, mywebbapp.com. Users registred with the webbapp chooses a username and gets a profilepage something like mywebbapp.com/a-username.

The web app connects to facebook. I could easily save the facebook user id in my db to connect the two, but it would be handy if I could save the webb app username to the facebook app/user. Much the same way you can save scores. Is this possible?

Comment: No, you can’t add your own info/data to Facebook user objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you won't be able to insert this into FB's db. Like you said, add to your db.

Comment: Right, it's not far off in terms of functionality. The Scores API is a use-case for the popular need of social games to keep track of users' scores. And it benefits users, developers, and FB. However, I'm not sure that storing a username is as popular and has the same impact.